# javascript function inside loop run only once

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a javascript function which is looping on my data basically I call another function inside of loop but it only execute once on last index here is my code and this function I wants to execute on every time.
  basically inside loop I call ajax that is run fine on each index of loop but issue is to call db.transaction function which is only execute on last index

> db.transaction(populateDB, errorCB);

```
function renderList(tx, results) {
   len = results.rows.length;
   console.log("rows" + results.rows.length);
   for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {

       (function (i) {
           var nid = results.rows.item(i).nId;

           $.ajax({
                type: 'post',
                url: 'http://localhost:50972/LibraryService.asmx/GetTitleSections',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: "{'MainSectionId':'" + nid + "'}",
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                async: false , 
                success: function (response) {
                    var data = response.d;
                    alert(data.nId);
                    TitleSectionData = data;
                },
                error: function (error) {
                    console.log(error);
                }
           });   
           db.transaction(TblTitleSection, errorCB);
       }) 
       (i);

       //  htmlstring += '<li>' + results.rows.item(i).strTitle + '</li>';
       // $('#resultList').append("<li>" + results.rows.item(i).strTitle + "</li>");
       $('#'+i).append( results.rows.item(i).strTitle );
       // $('#tblMainSection').append("<tr><td>" + results.rows.item(i).strTitle + "</td></tr>");
   }

   // $('#resultList').html(htmlstring);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you loop continues while running your ajax call. You could try putting the increment (i++) in your success function to force the loop to halt till the function is finished. Syntax seems to be okay.

replace:

```
for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
```

With:

```
for (var i = 0; i < len;){
```

And

```
success: function (response) {
    var data = response.d;
    alert(data.nId);
    TitleSectionData = data;
}
```

With:

```
success: function (response) {
    var data = response.d;
    alert(data.nId);
    TitleSectionData = data;
    i++;
}
```

See if that works :)

Comment: no that is not working ajax is running fine i wants to execute db.transaction(TblTitleSection, errorCB); this function on each iteration

Comment: ah I see, I read the question wrong ;). what does console.log("rows" + results.rows.length); return?